# Intitutive meaning the unit of Force $N$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, si-units

I infer 1 Newton of force = 1 kg.m/ sec squared means a force if acting continuosly on a body at rest would make it gain an acceleration of 1 m/sec squared each second.So the change in velocity is 1-0 = 1 m/sec.The body  would be at 1m distance from the initial point in 1 sec.The next second,the acceleration is (1+1)= 2m / sec squared.So the  velocity is 2m/sec.So, the body would be at (1+2) i.e. at 3m from the initial point,The next second, the acceleration is 3 m /sec squared. The body would move 3m from the last point ie 3m and would be at 6m from the origin.
Is my inference right?

Comment: With a force of 1 N applied to an object with mass 1 kg over 1 second, you are correct that the speed of the object at time = 1 s would be 1 m/s. But the object would not have traveled 1 m. Look up "kinematic equations" for the relationship between acceleration, velocity, and distance.

Comment: No you don't gain acceleration.  For a given force and mass you have constant acceleration.   You gain speed and travel a distance.

Answer (score 0):

For a constant acceleration $a$ the speed is given by $v(t) = at + v_0$, where $v_0$ is the initial velocity, as you correctly used. But to find the distance you would have to integrate the last question to find that: $x(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2 + v_0 t+ x_0$, where $x_0$ is the initial position. You can then check your results and you will find that they are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

Acceleration does not change at all because it is proportional to force applied and the force does not change. The effect of force does increase (sometimes decrease) something and that is velocity (speed if we are talking one dimensional). Also velocity increases continuously. It is not like it changes after every one second.

If acceleration is 1 m/s$^2$ then velocity increases by 1 m/s every second, meaning, when you measure the velocity every one second it will be greater by 1 m/s than it was before.
If you measure the velocity before that 1 s interval then velocity will still be higher but not by 1 m/s. The increase will be 1 m/s$^2 \times \Delta t$.

In your calculations you assume the object to move at a constant speed in each one second interval which is not the case.

Let us now do maths and approach intuitively as you wish.

**At t=0**

Object is at rest and acceleration=1m/s$^2$, but velocity is still zero.

**Few moments after start but less than one second**

Velocity is non-zero, and object moves but not at 1 m/s because it takes one complete second from start to reach 1 m/s. So it is moving a little slower than 1 m/s.

Now if the object had moved at 1 m/s throughout the one second interval it would have covered  1 m . But we saw it moves a little slower in the beginning and gradually increases speed. So overall it covers a distance less than 1 m in one second.

To find how much it has covered we have to do the math part.

distance varies linearly with time

velocity varies linearly with time(due to acceleration)

So distance varies quadratically with time.

Apply the corresponding equations of laws of motions, you will get
distance covered in

1 s$\rightarrow$0.5 m

2 s$\rightarrow$2 m

3 s$\rightarrow$4.5 m

Hope you understand